# Why .where() query in angularfirestore does not take variable for value for firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire

I need to get documents from Order collection based on the field sellerId, and its value should be similar with the currently logged in user. So, firstly I get the currently logged in users detail and assigned it to the userId,

```
    productList: Array<any> = [];
    profileInfo: any = {};
    userId: string = '';

  getUserProfile() {
    this.firebaseAuthService.getAuthState().subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.profileInfo = user.toJSON();
      }
      var userinfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.profileInfo));

      this.userId = userinfo.email;
      if(typeof this.userId==='string')
      {
        console.log('user--info--', this.userId);
      }
    });
  }
```

Then,  I tried to get the collection based on the query.

```
  getProductList() {

    return this.db.collection('Order',ref => ref.where('sellerId','==',this.userId)).valueChanges().subscribe(result=>{
      console.log('result',result);
      this.productList=result;
    }, (error)=>{
      this.widgetUtilService.presentToast(error.message);
    });
  }
```

It does not return anything, but if I enter the value for the .where(), I can get the desired result.

```
  getProductList() {

    return this.db.collection('Order',ref => ref.where('sellerId','==','user@gmail.com')).valueChanges().subscribe(result=>{
      console.log('result',result);
      this.productList=result;
    }, (error)=>{
      this.widgetUtilService.presentToast(error.message);
    });
  }
```

However, the value of the logged in user will be changing based on the user. I have tried using .valueOf(), which is not working as well.

[My database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGBT8.png)

Comment: Variables are always valid arguments.  You should log the value of `this.userId` at the beginning of `getProductList`.  What is it?  Did you call `getProductList` before the authentication completed successfully?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @DougStevenson , the problem was `getProductList` was called even before the authentication was completed. So there wasn't a valid value assigned to `userId`  used in the query.